# TypeError: Return argument type tuple(int_const 23,bool,uint8[3] memory) is not convertible to expected type tuple(uint256,bool,uint256[3] memory)

Tags: arrays, blockchain, ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts

//When I compile and deploy below code. It gives me no error

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT 
pragma solidity ^0.8.0; 
contract MultipleValues{
function returnValues() public pure returns (uint, bool, uint8[3] memory) {
    return (23, true, [1,2,3]);
}
}
```

//But when I change value from uint8[3] to uint[3] then it throws error

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;
contract MultipleValues{function returnValues() public pure returns (uint, bool, uint[3] memory) {
return (23, true, [1,2,3]);
}
}
```

```
//how to resolve this issue?
//Unexpected behaviour of array in solidity when returning a fixed size array
```

Answer (score 0):

this should work:

```
contract MultipleValues{
    function returnValues() public pure returns (uint, bool, uint[3] memory) {
        uint[3] memory memoryArray;
        memoryArray[0]=1;
        memoryArray[1]=2;
        memoryArray[2]=3;
        return (23, true, memoryArray);
}
```

`uint` types in solidity are `uint8,uint16,uint24,.....,uint256`. The smallest one is `uint8` and when the compiler sees "[1,2,3]" it infers the smallest uint type which is `uint8`. Actually "[1,2,3]" can be any of `uint8,uint16,uint24,.....,uint256`

What I did was, explicitly told the compiler that I am creating "uint[3]" and returning it.